# Can you quit a side quest in Assassin's Creed 2?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I decided to do a side quest, but figured out that its to hard for me, is there any way to quit it? (I'm using a pc if it helps)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the pause menu (press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on PC) and choose *Abort Memory* to jump out of whatever mission you're currently pursuing, removing whatever objective you're aiming for and allowing you to take new missions.

I believe any progress in the current memory will be irreversibly lost.